# NetLogo - exchanging variable values across links or agentsets (not within breeds)

Tags: hyperlink, netlogo, agentset

I am building a NetLogo model that tries to explain how agents find information they need to make a decision by bumping into other agents as they move about a space. There are three types of agents, each type has their own behavior rules and interact with their environment in different ways. The three types of agents, however, are all part of the same organization [Organization A].

The code below shows the breed names and the kinds of variables I'm using.

```
breed [Implementers Implementer];; Member of Organization A
breed [IMDeployeds IMDeployed];; Member of Organization A
breed [IMremotes IMremote];; Member of Organization A
... [other breeds]
Turtles-own [exchangeinfo holdinfo inforelevant infoarray 
taskcomplexity done];; is an info exchange going to happen, does the 
turtle have info, is info relevant, and then an array
extensions [array]
globals [complete routinemeeting]
```

**I want to do three things:**
1&2 Create a mechanism that joins the IMRemotes to the IMDeployeds and the IMDeployeds to the Implementers. 
(I've already tried creating links - I'm not sure that the mechanism does what I want the third thing to do:) 
3: Periodically check in with the agents that are linked together to cross-check variable values so that "information" can be "exchanged". Code I have for when agents are in the same space and can use "turtles-here" is below:

```
ask Implementers [
ifelse any? other Implementers [have-info-same-team] [change-location]
ifelse any? IMDeployeds-here [have-info-same-team] [change-location]

end

to have-info-same-team
ifelse any? turtles-here with [holdinfo > 0] [checkarray9] [change-
location]
end

to checkarray9
ifelse any? other turtles-here with [array:item infoarray 9 > 0]
[array:set infoarray 9 1 set holdinfo 1 checkarray8][checkarray8]
end
```

[etc, checking each position from 9 down to 0 in the array until you've gotten all the new information from that agent that you need]

When I try to ask my-links to do any of these things [**so that the agents in the same organization, but different "functions, if you will, can have purposeful meetings rather than relying on being in the same space with each other to communicate**], I'm told that the procedure is a "turtle only" procedure or that infoarray is a turtle-only variable.

Any help or suggestions greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than asking the links to do these things, you want to ask the **turtles** at the other end of the links.  I don't know if you have created directed or undirected links, but something like

```
ask turtle-set [other-end] of my-out-links [do something]
```

or

```
ask my-out-links [ask other-end [do something]]
```

will make the ask of the turtles at the other end of the links to this turtle. (Note that `[other-end] of my-out-links` yields a list of turtles rather than a turtleset, thus the use of `turtle-set` to turn the list into a turtleset.  `my-out-links` seems to work with both directed and undirected links. See http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#my-out-links.)

Hope this helps,
Charles

Comment: `ask my-out-links [ ask other-end [ ... ] ]` is equivalent to `ask out-neighbors [ ... ]`

Comment: Thank you both! These answers are helpful. I'm coding again tomorrow and will see how this works. Much appreciated!